# SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = xxxx, port = 42376

Tags: networking, server, router

Using **Kubuntu 20.04**.

#### Projects

- Nest js server project runs on port 3000 on the local machine.
- flutter project that is tested on a physical device using local IP address in the local network `http://X.x.x.x:3000`.

#### Problem

These passed 3 days i couldn't connect to it from the same device and getting the error:

> SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = xxxx, port = 42376

where `xxxx` is my local ip address in my network.

#### Notes

- pining my local machine from my phone using [Ping](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.WisdomStar.Ping&hl=en&gl=US) application shows that all packets arrive to destination successfully.
- before few days, i have configured MAC filter table in the router (D-Link), which allows only the specified mac addresses to connect to the home network.
- i have also installed nginx and it's running on my local machine
- visiting local IP address in the phone's browser shows **Unreachable** error page.
- notice that the port of the server project is `3000` and on the error message is `42376`

#### Before answering

- i searched the web for the passed three days in many platforms but most of the solution points to checking everything is connected to the same network which in my case, they are.
- i don't have a firewall (`ufw`) setup nor i have ever opened it or used it.
- i checked my local ip address and it's correct

#### So

- is the problem from the mac filter configuration?
- is it something else on ubuntu that i don't know about?
- are the ports really different? if so, how to solve it?
- does this problem require setting a static route to my local machine in the router or in the OS? if so, how to do that?